# How to check if any object from list has value equal to variable in python?

Tags: python

I have list of objects of class Character wchich has x and y property. I have that function:

```
def printBoard(self):
    for y, row in enumerate(self.rows):
        for x, char in enumerate(row):
            if y == self.player.y and x == self.player.x:
                print(self.player.char, end='')
            else:
                print(char, end='')
                
        print()
```

It prints game board to console. If actual cursor x,y is equal to player's x and y, then it prints player's char.
I would like to iterate through list of objects, not only one player instance
`self.objects=[Character(x=0,y=2,char="O"), Character(x=2, y=5,char="Q")]`

How to do that? I have read something about comprehensions, but it's kind of black magic to me.

So my question is: How to check any object from list has value equal to variable in single if statement?

## solved

Ok, i made that, but the solution is ugly as a shit:

```
def printBoard(self):
  for y, row in enumerate(self.rows):
        #print("Y: ",y,end='')
        for x, char in enumerate(row):
            #print(',',x,end='')
            try:
                print(self.whatObjectIsOnGivenXY(x, y).char, end='')
            except AttributeError:
                print(char,end='')
        print()
def whatObjectIsOnGivenXY(self,x1,y1):
    for y, row in enumerate(self.rows):
        for x, char in enumerate(row):
            if (x, y) == (x1, y1):
                for gameObject in self.objects:
                    if (gameObject.x, gameObject.y) == (x1,y1):
                        return gameObject
    return None
```

Is there any better solution?

Comment: Why not use the built-in `any` function?

Comment: Start by writing a function `player_at(x, y)` which returns an object at the given point (or None if there's no such object).

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension:

```
def equalCoordinates():
    matches = [i for i in my_list if (i.x, i.y) == mouse.pos] 
    return matches
```

Comment: That's nice, but show him how to use that in his code.

Answer (score 0):

`self.objects=[o for o in [Character(x=0,y=2,char="O"), Character(x=2, y=5,char="Q")] if o.x == 2 and o.y == 5 ]`

assigns the second object in the list to self.objects.

```
def whatObjectIsOnGivenXY(self,x1,y1):
    for y, row in enumerate(self.rows):
        for x in range(len(row)):
            if (x, y) == (x1, y1):
                return [gameObject for gameObject in self.objects if (gameObject.x, gameObject.y)==(x,y)]
    return None
```

Now you get list of objects.

Comment: I saw your answer after just after i done that in ugly way above :)